# Select points in python imshow() plot with lasso or lassomanager

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, imshow

can anyone help me to select points in a 2D array colorpot I'm plotting with imshow() from matplotlib.
I found two examples using the lasso or LassoSelector from matplotlib:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/lasso_selector_demo.html
http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/lasso_demo.html

Unfortunately, I can't make them work for me with imshow and a 2d (typically 50x500) array. The examples work fine, but when using imshow, python complains about things like not being able to set a color.
I'm still fairly new to python. From what I understand, I have to get a collection from the data I send to imshow?
Below is some example code that is not working - I tried with both examples linked above, without success.
It would be great if someone can point me in the right direction, though I don't mind working code either : )
Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# use random sample data:
random_data = np.random.rand(5, 5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Need the plot data as collection to be used with the lasso?
pts = ax.add_collection(imshow(data, aspect='auto', origin='lower',picker=True),autolim=False)
data = [Datum(*xy) for xy in random_data]
lman = ps.LassoManager(ax, data)
```

Here the code from example linked above:

```
from matplotlib.widgets import Lasso
from matplotlib.colors import colorConverter
from matplotlib.collections import RegularPolyCollection
from matplotlib import path

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import nonzero
from numpy.random import rand


class Datum(object):
    colorin = colorConverter.to_rgba('red')
    colorout = colorConverter.to_rgba('blue')

    def __init__(self, x, y, include=False):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        if include:
            self.color = self.colorin
        else:
            self.color = self.colorout


class LassoManager(object):
    def __init__(self, ax, data):
        self.axes = ax
        self.canvas = ax.figure.canvas
        self.data = data

        self.Nxy = len(data)

#        facecolors = [d.color for d in data]
        self.xys = [(d.x, d.y) for d in data]
        self.ind = []
        fig = ax.figure
        self.collection = RegularPolyCollection(
            fig.dpi, 6, sizes=(100,),
            facecolors=facecolors,
            offsets=self.xys,
            transOffset=ax.transData)

        ax.add_collection(self.collection)

        self.cid = self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onpress)

    def callback(self, verts):
        facecolors = self.collection.get_facecolors()
        p = path.Path(verts)
        ind = p.contains_points(self.xys)
        self.ind = nonzero([p.contains_point(xy) for xy in self.xys])[0]
        for i in range(len(self.xys)):
            if ind[i]:
                facecolors[i] = colorConverter.to_rgba('red')
#                print ind
            else:
                facecolors[i] = colorConverter.to_rgba('blue')

        self.canvas.draw_idle()
        self.canvas.widgetlock.release(self.lasso)
        del self.lasso

    def onpress(self, event):
        if self.canvas.widgetlock.locked():
            return
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        self.lasso = Lasso(event.inaxes,
                           (event.xdata, event.ydata),
                           self.callback)
        # acquire a lock on the widget drawing
        self.canvas.widgetlock(self.lasso)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'test'

    data = [Datum(*xy) for xy in rand(5, 5)]

    ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 1), ylim=(0, 1), autoscale_on=False)
    lman = LassoManager(ax, data)

    plt.show()

    for i in lman.ind:
        print lman.xys[i]

    print len(lman.xys)
```

Edit: The example below works for me to select arbitrarily shaped regions from a 2d plot (not scatter or xy plot). Not pretty nor elegant, but that can wait:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import LassoSelector
from matplotlib.path import Path


data = np.random.rand(10, 5)
grid = np.indices(data.shape)

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.pcolormesh(data)
ind = []

def onselect(verts):
    global ind
#    print verts
    pp = Path(verts)
    grid = [(i,j) for j in xrange(int(data.shape[0])) for i in xrange(int(data.shape[0]))]
    ii = np.nonzero([pp.contains_point(xy) for xy in grid])
    ind = [grid[i] for i in ii[0]]

#    ind = pp.contains_points(grid)
#    print ind
lasso = LassoSelector(ax, onselect)

plt.draw()
plt.show()

print ind
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to interact and get the data out like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231120/interaction-with-pythons-matplotlib-figure-assign-value-to-selected-features/33231600#33231600

Comment: Thank you, that pointed me in the right direction (which was to go back to the basic onselect function in Lasso instead of using demo examples). I want to select arbitrary/irregular shapes, so I sticked with the Lasso widget, added example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are things you haven't defined in your code. But in any case this is a functional example using what you gave:

```
from matplotlib.widgets import Lasso
from matplotlib.colors import colorConverter
from matplotlib.collections import RegularPolyCollection
from matplotlib import path

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import nonzero
from numpy.random import rand

class Datum(object):
    colorin = colorConverter.to_rgba('red')
    colorout = colorConverter.to_rgba('blue')

    def __init__(self, x, y, include=False):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        if include:
            self.color = self.colorin
        else:
            self.color = self.colorout


class LassoManager(object):
    def __init__(self, ax, data):
        self.axes = ax
        self.canvas = ax.figure.canvas
        self.data = data

        self.Nxy = len(data)

        facecolors = [d.color for d in data]
        self.xys = [(d.x, d.y) for d in data]
        self.ind = []
        fig = ax.figure
        self.collection = RegularPolyCollection(
            fig.dpi, 6, sizes=(100,),
            facecolors=facecolors,
            offsets=self.xys,
            transOffset=ax.transData)

        ax.add_collection(self.collection)

        self.cid = self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onpress)

    def callback(self, verts):
        facecolors = self.collection.get_facecolors()
        p = path.Path(verts)
        ind = p.contains_points(self.xys)
        self.ind = nonzero([p.contains_point(xy) for xy in self.xys])[0]
        for i in range(len(self.xys)):
            if ind[i]:
                facecolors[i] = colorConverter.to_rgba('red')
#                print ind
            else:
                facecolors[i] = colorConverter.to_rgba('blue')

        self.canvas.draw_idle()
        self.canvas.widgetlock.release(self.lasso)
        del self.lasso

    def onpress(self, event):
        if self.canvas.widgetlock.locked():
            return
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        self.lasso = Lasso(event.inaxes,
                           (event.xdata, event.ydata),
                           self.callback)
        # acquire a lock on the widget drawing
        self.canvas.widgetlock(self.lasso)

data = np.random.rand(5, 5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# No, no need for collection
ax.imshow(data, aspect='auto', origin='lower',picker=True)
data = [Datum(*xy) for xy in rand(10, 2)]
lman = LassoManager(ax, data)
plt.show()
```

,here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately, I wasn't clear enough in my question and messed up the definition of the data I want to plot. The example works with 102 array (normal scatter, xy plot), but my data is a 2d colorplot. If I change data to e.g. 5x5, I can't create the Datum anymore, so the example doesn't work.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the plot. The Datum definition has x and y in its definition (two variables). When you do "data" that is 5x5 you are giving 5 variables into Datum. So it prompts an error.

Comment: You are right, it's not really a plotting problem, rather the data structure of the examples that I found.

Comment: The example is perfectly functional. You just need to convert your 5x5 grid into a series of points. (which I assume will take the form of a 5x5 grid)

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. I had the data in the wrong format to use on Datum, used an array instead of a list of tuples, working now.